# Search listview for multiple results

Tags: vb.net, listview, visual-studio-2013

I have accomplished to search my list view item, but unfortunately it shows the first result only and nothing beyond that

This is my code

```
Private Sub ULButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ULButton1.Click

        If ComboBox2.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an office")
        Else
            Dim itm As ListViewItem

            itm = Me.ListView2.FindItemWithText(TextBox1.Text)

            If Not itm Is Nothing Then
                ListView2.SelectedItems.Clear()
                ListView3.Clear()
                ListView3.View = View.Details
                ListView3.FullRowSelect = True
                ListView3.GridLines = True
                ListView3.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
                ListView3.Columns.Add("Username", CInt(ListView1.Width / 2))
                ListView3.Columns.Add("Name", CInt(ListView1.Width / 2))

                Me.ListView2.Items.Item(itm.Index).Selected = True
                For Each itm2 As ListViewItem In Me.ListView2.SelectedItems
                    Me.ListView3.Items.Add(ListView2.Items(itm2.Index).Clone())
                Next
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Not Found", "")
            End If

            itm = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
```

When I enter a string in the textbox, this code will show results of listview item in another listview, is there a way I can modify this to show multiple related items to the string I enter in the textbox?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

FindItemWithText finds only the first matching item.
You would need to use another form or that function that takes the starting index and keep finding next item in a loop.
Also, this fragment looks strange:

```
        Me.ListView2.Items.Item(itm.Index).Selected = True
        For Each itm2 As ListViewItem In Me.ListView2.SelectedItems
            Me.ListView3.Items.Add(ListView2.Items(itm2.Index).Clone())
        Next
```

You iterate over selected items, but you just selected one! An you already know it's index...

Comment: Thank you vlad, this fragment does the trick for me as I have two listviews, one is hidden and has a directory searcher, and the second listview shows up the search results

Comment: Two comments:
1. Your block of code is identical to one line:
Me.ListView3.Items.Add(ListView2.Items(itm.Index).Clone())

2. It is an overkill to use ListView for searches.